# Django | django-socialregistration error

Tags: django, facebook

I'm trying to add the facebook connect feature to my site, I decided to use [django socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration).All are setup including [pyfacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook), here is my source code.

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
    'socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^callback/$', 'fbproject.fbapp.views.callback'),
```

**views.py**

```
def callback(request):
    return render_to_response('canvas.fbml')
```

**Template**

```
<html>

<body>
{% load facebook_tags %}
{% facebook_button %}
{% facebook_js %}
</body>

</html>
```

but when I point to the URL, I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 279, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 73, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\socialregistration\middleware.py", line 13, in process_request
    request.facebook.check_session(request)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 1293, in check_session
    self.session_key_expires = int(params['expires'])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

**Django 1.1.1**
**Python 2.6.2**

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's definitely being caused because either the POST or GET variables have a bad value for `expires`. Check the form that you're using and the URL's query string to check this.

If you look at the code for `facebook/__init__.py` you'll see it only tries to set a value for  `self.session_key_expires` if `params` (which comes from either `request.POST` or `request.GET`) already has a value for `expires`.

Actually, might want to double check the code just to be sure. You should see lines like this in `facebook/__init__.py`:

```
    if params.get('expires'):
        self.session_key_expires = int(params['expires'])
```

If not, maybe you have a bad version?

**update**
Now that I think of it, the error message explicitly said that the value was none. Which probably means that they're not including the check `if param.get('expires')` because I believe that would return None and then resolve to `False`.

Unless you have the very latest copy of pyfacebook, try downloading it again.

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Just out of curiosity, what was the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in pyfacebook. See http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/issues#issue/26