# Facebook connect | Django exception

Tags: django, facebook

Continue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647729/django-django-socialregistration-error) question. I'm getting this error when running the application

```
Caught an exception while rendering: Tried xd_receiver in module myfirstapp.fbapp.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'xd_receiver'
   <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"],
            function() {
        FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", " {% url facebook_xd_receiver %} ")
            }
        );
        function facebookConnect(form){
            FB.Connect.requireSession();
            FB.Facebook.get_sessionState().waitUntilReady(
                function(){
                    form.submit();
                }
            );
        }
```

PS: Can somebody please tell me a good tutorial on django socialregistration (which covers all the basic steps) I'm a newbe, I tried facebook dev [tutorial](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:PyFacebook_Tutorial#Add_the_middleware) but that also didn't work..